# How to display custom post for user only in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress, i created custom post type and i want this should display only for subscriber only(not for admin ) So how can i do this Here is my current code?
function create_posttype() {

```
    register_post_type( 'UserProject',
           array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'UserProject' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'UserProject' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'UserProject'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
  
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
if ( current_user_can( 'editor' ) && is_user_logged_in()) {
    function book_setup_post_type() {
        $args = array(
            'public'    => true,
            'label'     => __( 'Books', 'textdomain' ),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
        );
        register_post_type( 'book', $args );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'book_setup_post_type' );
}
```

Book is a custom post type you can write your own code here.
Subscribers have no rights to the dashboard. You can set the condition for editor rule or another rule.